# JAva programming using buffreader

Tags: java, arrays, input

```
import java.io.*;  
public class Main {    
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{             
     String MidtermLecGrade, MidtermLabGrade;
     String FinalLecGrade, FinalLabGrade;
     Float MG, temp;
     Float FG;
     Float Average;
     Float SemG;
     double a =0.6;
     double b = 0.4;



    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter your Midterm Lecture Grade:");    
    MidtermLecGrade=br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your Midterm Lab Grade:");    
    MidtermLabGrade=br.readLine();

    temp= (a * MidtermLecGrade) + (b*MidtermLabGrade);
    MG = Float.parseFloat(temp);
    System.out.println("Your Midterm Grade is :" + MG);

    }    
}   



error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
        temp= (a * MidtermLecGrade) + (b*MidtermLabGrade);
                 ^
  first type:  double
  second type: String
 error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
        temp= (a * MidtermLecGrade) + (b*MidtermLabGrade);
                                        ^
  first type:  double
  second type: String
 error: incompatible types: Float cannot be converted to String
        MG= Float.parseFloat(temp);


          ^
```

Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output

Comment: `a` is `double`, `MidtermLecGrade` is a `String`, you can't multiple a `double` with a `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert a and b variables to float. 
Also you need parse the user input to float.
No need for other variables.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String MidtermLecGrade, MidtermLabGrade;

        Float temp;
        float a = 0.6f;
        float b = 0.4f;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter your Midterm Lecture Grade:");
        MidtermLecGrade = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your Midterm Lab Grade:");
        MidtermLabGrade = br.readLine();

        temp = ((a * Float.parseFloat(MidtermLecGrade)) + (b * Float.parseFloat(MidtermLabGrade)));
        System.out.println("Your Midterm Grade is :" + temp);

    }
```

Comment: what is f after the 0.6 and 0.4?

Comment: to tell compiler to treat it as float explicitly  we need to  use f or F

Answer (score 0):

```
String MidtermLecGrade, MidtermLabGrade;
double a =0.6;
double b = 0.4;
//...
temp= (a * MidtermLecGrade) + (b*MidtermLabGrade);
```

`a` is a `double`
`MidtermLecGrade` is a `String`

`double * String` makes no sense, hence your error

At a guess, you will need to convert the `String` value to a `Double`.  See [`Double.parseDouble(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

Comment: can u help me to fix it?

Comment: I just did, but you will need to make some effort in understanding how the suggestion will fix your problem

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(MidtermLecGrade)` - this may throw an `NumberFormatException` so you will need to deal with that. You can see [java convert string to double](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+convert+string+to+double&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) for a lot more details.